# How can I define authentication related routes in laravel8?

Tags: laravel, authentication

I followed tutorials and using the below commands I installed all the files needed for register user, login, etc:

composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui vue --auth

now I have Auth directory in my controllers list and also new forms for register users, login, home and etc are automatically created, I added a link on my page to enter me to registration form, but when I add user,  after I hit the register button it says home not found and shows me 404 error which is about route, where I have added Auth::routes(); already to my web blade page. I checked the database, the user is successfully added to the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add `redirectTo` property to your auth controller. It's default to `/home` and you're getting 404 cause you don't have this route.

Comment: uw, and also don't forget to mark it as correct answer for other people to find it useful